# How to show window after pressing X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm writing a Mac OS X application using Xcode 6 and Objective C.

After starting the application and press the X, the window will be hidden. Is there a way to show up the window with clicking on the App-Symbol on the dock (like in Safari)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On clicking "X" or close dot then window closes and if it's a root Window then your app will be closed. So if you want to hide on clicking "X" or close dot then you could use below:-

```
//Called when clicked close option on window
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed: (NSApplication *) theApplication
{
  [[NSApplication sharedApplication] hide:self];
  return NO;
}

//Called when you tap app icon on dock.
-(BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)sender hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag{
  [[self.mainWindowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
  return YES;
}
```

But remember when we hide a OS X app then after a certain time the OS will sleep that app ,called NSAppNap will take place and your background work will be delayed or simply OS will perform those operation in a batching form.

Comment: Thanks for the great code example and good explaining. It works perfectly like I was expecting it

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the "X" (or red "Close" dot), that actually fully closes the window and does not hide it.

To make the window reappear (assuming it's still in memory and not released thanks to ARC), you need to do ["`showWindow`" on the window controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/showWindow:).  And when clicking on the dock icon, the best place to catch the dock icon being clicked might be [NSApplicationDelegate's "`applicationDidBecomeActive:`" notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:).

Comment: The first comment isn't truth, because I can still see the application icon on the dock. Why would it totally close and keep the app icon on the dock after pressing "X"? The answer from walle84 actually solve it